# Converting -48 VDC to +12 or +24 VDC 10 Amps or more

Tags: led, controller, lighting

Good day,

I would like the simplest way to reliably convert -48 VDC (Telcom DC Plant -42 through -56) to either +12 VDC or +24 VDC, the crux is I need at least 10 Amps.

What I am trying to do is build an LED Strip Lighting controller powered from the Telcom DC Plant. These Strips could be up to 10 Meters (Average length of an Aisle).

I'm thinking a switched buck converter but am open to any / all ideas.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the best method is probably buy one if you don't know the basics, you can buy 24V strip leds and just cascade in series direct off battery

Comment: Just ON/OFF lighting? Or, when you say "strip lighting controller" do you actually mean that you have fancier things to do?

Comment: Can the -48V bus supply in excess of 12 to 24W

Comment: Tony Stewart, coming off a (FAP) fuse access panel, I now I could wire them to be powered from -48, but I want to control them.

Comment: Jonk, yes. I want to add a PIR, low level lighting until someone is in the Aisle, then full brightness. Possibly a color other than white then white when the PIR detects someone.

Comment: JonRB, yes. The bus itself can supply multiple kilowatts.

Comment: What powers the Arduino (as I now understand you to be using?) Can or should its control circuitry be isolated (optically, for example) from the -48 V rail and LED circuits? Or is there a forced common galvanic voltage reference (such as the -48V's ground?)

Comment: jonk, I was going to cheat on the 5vdc for the Arduino by using a Dollar store car cell phone charger and operate it off the 12 vdc. The 12 volt and 5 volt portions of the circuit will be isolated from the -48 volt ground because the -48 plant has a positive return / ground.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to convert polarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frnycd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

If you use a step-down DC-DC power supply you can run the LEDs as shown in Figure 1.

- You need to make sure your power supply hasn't got an internal ground connection on the negative output.
- You need to make sure that your LED lightgs aren't grounded on their negative terminals.

Comment: Transistor, this is, in theory, what I am attempting. The step-down DC-DC converters I am finding can't handle the amperage.

Comment: Can you series connect your LED lamps? Four identical 12 V LED strip lights could be wired in series on a 48 V supply. No need for a converter.

Comment: Transistor, maybe. I am hoping to use an Arduino to control them, low level / color unoccupied to bright / white when a PIR detects someone in the area.